# How to submit a package to PyPI under a different user than my ~/.pypirc

Tags: setuptools, pypi

As far as I can tell from the docs, unlike with say git and `.gitignore` files, setuptools will only look in your `$HOME` directory for a `.pypirc` file.

Mostly I am submitting as 'myself', but now I want to submit a specific project via my employer's dev team account.

`setup.py register --help` doesn't seem to indicate any way to supply a username/password other than the one from my `~/.pypirc`

There's the `setup.cfg` file which could appear in my project root, but it seems that only allows to specify args accepted by the command, so same as above.

Same for `.pydistutils.cfg` (?)

Surely I can't be the only one - what's the usual way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine

After installing twine I was able to create a project-specific `.pypirc` file in the project root, containing the company username/password.

Before using twine you have to generate the package using `setup.py` though, so the procedure is (from your project root):

```
$ python setup.py sdist
$ twine register --config-file=./.pypirc dist/*
$ twine upload --config-file=./.pypirc dist/*
```